# Get the app state in FromRequest implementation

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have an actix web server and I want to get the state of my server within a `FromRequest` implementation.

I'd tried something like:

```
impl FromRequest for User {
    type Config = ();
    type Error = Error;
    type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<User, actix_web::Error>>>>;

    fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, pl: &mut Payload, state: web::Data<State>) -> Self::Future {
       ...
    }
}
```

But of course, this doesn't work since `from_request` asks for 2 arguments only, not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, pl: &mut Payload) -> Self::Future {
   let _state = req.app_data::<Data<State>>();
   ....
}
```

See docs for [app_data](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/struct.HttpRequest.html#method.app_data)